# Idiom for the need to expose oneself to something they don't believe in, to broaden the mind

Tags: idiom-requests

As an example consider the following:

> Atheists must read some religious literature now and then to make sure they are not trapped in their own filter bubble of thinking.

I remember hearing an idiom to capture this. Kinda like the idiom - "You must know your friends well, but your enemies even better."

Comment: It doesn't quite pass as an answer but an emphasis on knowledge over ideological-piety is given by Rudyard Kipling's ‘There is no sin so great as ignorance' and 'there is no sin but ignorance' from 'The Jew of Malta' though in the latter case he disparages religion in the same breath...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think you may be confused about the idiom you mention. It's usually rendered as "keep your friends close, and your enemies closer." I've never seen it contain "know", or even make reference to that.

Comment: I went to a crazy people's church once. It was a "**culturally enriching experience**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before judging someone, walk a mile in their shoes*

> To spend time trying to consider or understand another person's perspectives, experiences, or motivations before making a judgment about them.

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+a+mile+in+my+shoes)

(As the jokes goes: because then you will be a mile away and they will have no shoes.)

Answer (score 1):

An informal phrase is

> **don't knock it until you've tried it** - idiom
>
> Definition of don't knock it until you've tried it —used to tell a person that he or she
>   should try something before criticizing it
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/don't%20knock%20it%20until%20you've%20tried%20it

---

You may be thinking of

The phrase "**know thy enemy**" comes from the ancient Chinese general Sun Tzu.

The full quote is:

> "Know thy enemy and know yourself; in a hundred battles, you will
>   never be defeated. When you are ignorant of the enemy but know
>   yourself, your chances of winning or losing are equal. If ignorant
>   both of your enemy and of yourself, you are sure to be defeated in
>   every battle."
>   https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090111114125AARe9kS

Answer (score 0):

One can be oneself one's own enemy. "Know yourself and you will know the universe and the gods" Pato, It is the awakening

Comment: Perhaps my question isn't clear? I'm specifically looking for the idiom that encourages one to indulge in the *opposite* of what one believes in, to be aware of the other perspective.

Answer (score 0):

*Open one's eyes*

This indicates generally exposing oneself to something that before they were metaphorically "blind" to

*Burst one's bubble*

Use this if someone has had their previous opinion/mindset suddenly shattered by exposure to different viewpoints

Comment: Can you provide references, please? I'm not sure that bursting one's bubble really fits in this context.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary defines it as "to say or do something that shows someone that their beliefs are false"
It may be more applicable to the consequence of broadening one's mind but it still answers the question methinks
"He looked into the topic more broadly, and found that the truth burst his bubble"